# daily percentage with mongo or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, aggregate

Hello all 
 I'd like to calculate the daily percentage with mongo aggregate or pandas: 
 do you have any idea on how to proceed ?
This percentage has to be calculated for a given class of articles, for a given date (cf example below).

 The original data does not have 'percent' value 
Thank you for your help !

Original data:

```
[{
  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 9,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",

},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",

},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 " :,

},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",


},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "13/01/2022 ", 

}
]
```

Target :

```
[{
  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 9,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  "percent" :  0.9 #( = (9/(1+9) ) 90% of 'CODE_1' devices are ok  the 11/01/2022
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  "percent":  0.1 # 1/(1+9) # here are the 10% of failed 'CODE_1' for 11/01/2022
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 " :,
  "percent" : 0.5 # 8/(8+8 # another device : 50% of 'CODE_2' devices are failed this day
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  "percent" : 0.5 # 8/(8+8)
  
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "13/01/2022 ", 
  "percent" : 1 # no failed devices code_1 this day
}
]
```

Comment: What would be the desired end result for the data you've shown, and why?

Comment: I updated my question (the only difference between original data and calculated is the percent field).
I'd like to monitor the daily failure rate of many equipments

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Pandas or MongoDB.

If you have that data, just good ol' `collections.defaultdict` and `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections


data = [ ... ]  # from above

by_status = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.Counter())
for datum in data:
    is_ok = datum["Status"] == "OK"
    key = (datum["DateOfExtraction"].strip(), datum["CODE_ARTICLE"].strip())
    by_status[key][is_ok] += datum["NumberOfArticles"]

for (date, article), statuses in by_status.items():
    percent = statuses[True] / sum(statuses.values())
    print(date, article, percent)
```

prints out

```
11/01/2022 CODE_1 0.9
11/01/2022 CODE_2 0.5
13/01/2022 CODE_1 1.0
```

Comment: It would work for a reasonnable amount of data , but i 've something like 1.5M lines ....

Comment: Happily, it works just as well for more data. Replace `data` with a generator function that queries your database for batches of items at a time.